# "Render Current Frame" in Maya with Python

Tags: python, maya, autodesk, pymel

How can I use pymel, or just python in general, to render the current frame with whatever settings are given?

I've looked into pymel.core.rendering, but all I can find are render specific commands. I tried the basic cmds.render() but it didn't do anything.

I basically want the same functionality as the "Render Current Frame"-Button at the top of the UI - that it renders the currently active view with whatever the settings are.

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by looking at the script editor. It's within the runtime module. So for anyone else with this problem, the command is:

pymel.Core.runtime.RenderIntoNewWindow()